# Realizar consulta directa

Tags: c#, ado.net

tengo mi siguiente consulta en c# estoy utilizando el ADO.NET Entity Framework 4, mi consulta solo quiero obtener los datos de dos columnas especificas.

```
     public List<clsSalidas> Listar()
    {
        try
        {
            var lista = contexto.ExecuteStoreQuery<clsSalidas>("Select T_Doc, C_F from SALIDASDOC");
            return lista;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje

```
No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Entidades.clsSalidas>' en 
 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Entidades.clsSalidas>'
```

Como verán no encuentro como solucionarlo. espero me ayuden.

Comment: la conversion explicita no funciona?

Comment: La solución de [@Julian Solarte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/14150/julian-solarte) debería funcionar y tu código ya compilaría. En caso de excepción en runtime, valida que los nombres de las columnas en el query estén bien y que los nombres de las propiedades de tu clase **clsSalidas** sean los mismos que los de las columnas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas probable es que tu consulta no este retornando una lista, si no otra cosa, lo mas probable es que este retornando un enum, simplemente basta con agregar ToList() al metodo de consulta.

```
 contexto.ExecuteStoreQuery<clsSalidas>("Select T_Doc, C_F from SALIDASDOC").ToList();
```

Si tu problema no se soluciona asi, te recomiendo hacer un debug a tu programa y colocar un breakpoint ahi, asi puedes ver que tipo de variable retorna y puedas hacer la conversion